# Loading WPF DataModel With File Data

Tags: wpf

I'm wondering what is the best way to iterate through the contents of a file directory and load these filenames up into a Heirarchical Data Model in WPF?  The file structure I have is:

c:\wpfproject\root
             \root\firstlevel
             \root\firstlevel\firstsublevel

Is there some way in .NET to read the file names from a c:\drive including all sub-directories.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories(...)
```

and

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(...)
```

You would need to create a recursive method using these functions to enumerate the entire drive.

See the documentation for the [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) class.